# What does the "Suppress Public Notifications" option do?

Tags: league-of-legends

I noticed there was an option (within the client) to "Suppress Public Notifications". I enabled it, and from what I can tell it doesn't change anything. Is this just unimplemented or what is it for?

Here is a screenshot of the option:

[image: Suppress Public Notifications]

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of the button is to block all messages about game leavers and people not accepting into games; however, the button is currently not working.

Answer (score -1):

I think it may be for not seeing things such as server down-age messages, etc.

Comment: save your conjectures to yourself or to comments please